# Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mono, localhost

When I run `node app.js`, I get the following error:

```
Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Express server listening on port 3000
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/me/development/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:553:74)
    at emit (events.js:118:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/me/development/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:140:15)
    at emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/me/developmen/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:512:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at net.js:451:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I'm not sure whether this is localhost problem or an issue with the connection to mongodb. I tried looking at similar questions SO and Github but it didn't help me.

Comment: Is `mongod` running? If so you should be able to get into the mongo shell with `mongo` from the command line

Comment: @azium How do I check if `mongod` is running? Just in case you have a different way of checking it than I do.

Comment: just type `mongo` on your command line. should see something like this: http://i.imgur.com/Elu8Zjp.png

Comment: @azium The command was not found. However when I deploy this app to Heroku the webapp works fine. Can both these scenarios happen at the same time?

Comment: Yes because Heroku will be smart and start any services it needs. Did you ever install mongo locally?

Comment: @azium perhaps not. I will try to work it out.

Comment: Alternatively you can hook into an mongo instance in the cloud. https://mongolab.com/ lets you create free ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like mongodb server is not running. Check it

Comment: If it is by doing `ps -edaf | grep mongo` or `ps as | grep mongo` then it doesn't appear in the list of running processes. However, when I deploy the app to heroku it works. What makes it work in Heroku and not locally?

Comment: Official website says that you can start MongoDB using `sudo service mongod start` comand. Try it

Comment: It says `sudo: service: command not found`. I guess I have to install it locally.

Comment: @maregor  I suppose that you need to install MongoDB. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/ Installation is very simple, just follow the instruction